# Stepping down 400v to 50v in DC

Tags: step-down

I have a 400V supply and I need to step it down to 50V, does anyone know a good way to do this? I need a solution that can work quickly (for the circuit) and doesn't catch anything on fire

Comment: For 1mA? 100A? It matters.  Is galvanic isolation required? Also matters.

Comment: The goal is to get to 5A, I believe that galvanic isolation is not required. I am taking a 400V battery and trying to get to 50V for a pcb.

Comment: Have you looked into buck converters if you don’t need isolation or flyback if you do?

Comment: Can’t you wire out just few cells from whole battery?